# "include?" method works differently with the same string passed as array element and as string

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain why when I try to check if a text includes a string by passing it as an array element and as a whole string, I get different results?

```
bullets[30]
#=> "eines Zahnes), da es zu einer verstärkten Blutungsneigung kommen kann; Der behandelnde Arzt sollte über die Einnahme des Medikamentes informiert werden. "

desc.include?(bullets[30])
#=> false

desc.include?("eines Zahnes), da es zu einer verstärkten Blutungsneigung kommen kann; Der behandelnde Arzt sollte über die Einnahme des Medikamentes informiert werden. ")
#=> true

bullets[30].class
#=> String
```

Comment: Share `desc` value too, please, to make your example reproducible...

Comment: Compare their [`bytes`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#bytes-method) or [`codepoints`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#codepoints-method) and you should find a difference. (my guess: the trailing space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why when I try to check if a text includes a string by passing it as an array element and as a whole string, I get different results?

The only possible explanation is that the two strings are not equal.

- They could have different encodings (e.g. one is UTF-8, one is ISO8859-15).
- They could have different Unicode normalizations, e.g. the `ä` in one string could be the [U+00E4 *Latin small letter a with diaeresis*](https://compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E4) and the other uses a [U+0061 *Latin small letter a*](https://compart.com/en/unicode/U+0061) and a [U+0308 *Combining character diaeresis*](https://compart.com/en/unicode/U+0308).
- One of the strings could have a Unicode Byte-Order-Mark.
- One of the strings could have additional invisible whitespace.
- One of the strings could have additional non-printable characters.
- The strings could have different whitespace, e.g. one string has a normal space, the other has a non-breaking space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude! **One of the strings could have additional non-printable characters** - that was the issue